# MongoiDB use a String for _id

Tags: java, mongodb, scala, casbah

I'd like to use a unique string per collection to id a doc. I'm using Scala and Casbah but can also use Java if needed.

I know I should use Casbah `collection.createIndex` but I don't understand the scaladocs.

If my case class is :

```
case class GroupParams (
  _id: String,
  //groupId: String,
  testPeriodStart: DateTime, // ISO8601 date
  variants: Seq[String], //["17","18"]
  testPeriodEnd: Option[DateTime])
```

and I will always use the _id to reference a particular document (no need for `_id: ObjectId`).

I don't care about sorting/ordering since these will only be accessed as individual docs, never cursored through. There seems no reason to have the overhead of another index on the default  `_id: ObjectId`.

How to I create the index on the collection with  `_id: String` using Casbah? If I should create a new index and leave the default alone can you show how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo automatically creates index for _id field for all types (ObjectId, String or whatever you want) - [mongo indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/)

Answer (score 0):

Mongo automatically generate a  `_id` to your index in the collection,
if you want to insert `String` to the `_id` you can convert a String to `objectId` like this : `ObjectId.Parse(myString))`

> See more in the [MongoDB API](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/1.3.1/html/3321e7aa-fe9b-4940-be93-019ff33fed5d.htm)